# Setting LiveData value from RxJava observable (Android)

Tags: java, android, mvvm, rx-java, android-livedata

I have a `LiveData` in my repository class which is being observed (through a viewmodel of course) in an activity (I am using MVVM architecture) and when button is clicked, an API is called using Retrofit which returns an RxJava2 `Observable` (not a `Call`) because I need RxJava2 to zip together 2 api calls. The requested data from the API should then be set as the `LiveData`'s new value. This is the `Observable` which is created from the Retrofit API calls:

```
Observable.zip(retrofitService.getData(), retrofitService.getData2(),
                    new BiFunction<List<float[]>, List<float[]>, List<Object>>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public List<Object> apply(@NonNull List<float[]> floats, @NonNull List<float[]> floats2) throws Exception {
                             // combine the two different api calls 
                            List<Object> newlist = ...
                            return newList;
                        }
                    });
```

Naturally, if another button is clicked in my app, another API is called.
Now my question is, how can I update the `LiveData`'s value from an Observable (like for example the one given above). I know of the `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher()` method, but I am unsure how to apply this here. Is the only way then to subscribe to the observable and then call postvalue on the livedata?

```
Observable.zip(retrofitService.getData(), retrofitService.getData2(),
                    new BiFunction<List<float[]>, List<float[]>, List<Object>>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public List<Object> apply(@NonNull List<float[]> floats, @NonNull List<float[]> floats2) throws Exception {
                             // combine the two different api calls 
                            List<Object> newlist = ...
                            return newList;
                        }
                    }).subscribe(list -> repository.updateLiveData(list));
```

My apologies for the vague explanation, I am having a hard time expressing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

Note the .toFlowable().

```
    LiveData<?> liveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(Observable.zip(retrofitService.getData(), retrofitService.getData2(),
            new BiFunction<List<float[]>, List<float[]>, List<Object>>() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public List<Object> apply(@NonNull List<float[]> floats, @NonNull List<float[]> floats2) throws Exception {
                    // combine the two different api calls 
                    List<Object> newlist = ...
                    return newList;
                }
            }).toFlowable().subscribe(list -> repository.updateLiveData(list)));
```